# Iterate though the table rows select only specific column names and values

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner and have no clue of how to fetch the data from JSON. I have the following JSON structure,

```
{
"title": "Delicate style of embroidery lawn dress",
"field": [
    {
        "row1": {
            "key": "free_homedelivery",
            "value": "yes"
        }
    },
    {
        "row2": {
            "key": "_price",
            "value": "60"
        }
    },
    {
        "row3": {
            "key": "_regular_price",
            "value": "60"
        }
    },
    {
        "row4": {
            "key": "_stock_status",
            "value": "instock"
        }
    }
         ]
}
```

I tried this but the console say `undefined`

```
for(var i =0 ;i < s.length; i++)
{
console.log('key ' + s.field['row'+i].key);
}
```

This doesn't seem to fetch the values...

`Here is the Fiddle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems

1. What is `s`? - Assuming `s` is the json you have pasted
2. Iteration is on `s.field`, but `s.length` is used
3. Referring to `field` as an array but trying to access a property of an object inside the array as a property of the array.
4. Array iteration starts from `0`, and the `row` name is starting with `row1`

.

```
var numFields = s.field.length; // Good practice to keep length calculated
for(var i = 0; i < numFields; i++){
    console.log('key ' + s.field[i]['row'+(i+1)].key);
}
```

**Foot Note** - The JSON is too complicated, it can be as simple as below,

```
var s = {
    "title": "Delicate style of embroidery lawn dress",
    "field": [
        {
            "key": "free_homedelivery",
            "value": "yes"
        },
        {
            "key": "_price",
            "value": "60"
        }
    ]
};
// Updated loop
var numFields = s.field.length; // Good practice to keep length calculated
for(var i = 0; i < numFields; i++){
    console.log('key ' + s.field[i].key);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n4J5U/

Comment: console does not return anything.

Comment: Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/n4J5U/. You might have missed assigning your JSON to `var s`

Comment: here is the URL that generate the JSON  http://ezinfotec.com/api/api.php?method=singleitem&pid=1055 i'm using $.ajax({ }); to fetch JSON

Comment: I tried the fiddle code but still console says 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined '

Comment: You need to get the response into a variable and then use the above looping. Anyway what browser are you trying it on?

Comment: trying in chrome. I've assigned s like this success: function(s){ your code goes here }

Comment: Ok, why don't you create a fiddle and link it

Comment: Two issues with your fiddle - 1. jQuery is not added in the fiddle
2. `x.pid` is not defined. Updated fiddle link that works - http://jsfiddle.net/MwS5r/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your objects in the json are all a bit different (the property name is row1, row2 etc) so you would have to do something like this:

```
var json = {
    "title": "Delicate style of embroidery lawn dress",
        "field": [{
        "row1": {
            "key": "free_homedelivery",
                "value": "yes"
        }
    }, {
        "row2": {
            "key": "_price",
                "value": "60"
        }
    }, {
        "row3": {
            "key": "_regular_price",
                "value": "60"
        }
    }, {
        "row4": {
            "key": "_stock_status",
                "value": "instock"
        }
    }]
}

for (i = 0; i < json.field.length ; i++){
    var item = json.field[i];    
    var key = item["row" + (i + 1)].key;
    alert(key);
}
```

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jheW/)

Comment: See the fiddle, there is no error. Have you forgot to declare the variable (I named it json).

Comment: you have stored the json in a variable directly. Check the fiddle in my post you will get an idea about my code.